# Low accuracy in out of time validation

Tags: logistic

I prepared a model which had very good accuracy (80.5%) on my out of sample data. However when I ran that model on a population which is some 6mths old the accuracy went down to abysmal 33%. I am talking here about percentage detection of event (say defaulters). So right now my model is only detecting 33 out of 100 defaulters in the out of time dataset.

Please suggest what can be the possible reasons behind this. How do I go about improving this? It'd be tough to defend this accuracy before the client. God forbid, if required to defend this accuracy before the client, how could this be justified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious culprit for your problem is probably [spurious relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship). You identified relationships which deemed significant for certain period of time, but they are not significant for all periods of time. [Lucas critique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_critique) might apply too.

When dealing with models of economic activity it is always prudent to define the time boundaries of the model (i.e. for which time period the model is applicable) or include time in the model. It seems you are building your model on snapshots at specific time-periods, try using panel-data framework, this will help you to see which covariates remain significant for all time periods.

Comment: My model has around 25 variables out of which 18 are categorical. I build my categories in it keeping in mind the business significance of each category. Can you please elaborate how could I have injected the spurious relationship ? Any other things I could dig into ?

Comment: @ayush, my answer was based on information you supplied. As always I could be wrong. The problem with the spurious regressions is that there are only special cases where you can guard explicitly against them (unit root processes). If you are really sure that the relationships in your model are not spurious, then the problem lies elsewhere. As I tried to say, maybe relationship changed in time.

Comment: how can one find out whether these relationships changed in time or not ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that you expect that the other data set should have similar characteristics to your original data set. I only consider myself a beginner in this area, but it sounds likely that you "over-fitted" your model to the sample data. This means fitting to random noise in the data, as though it is a real effect that would be observed on a new data set. A likely cause is having too many parameters relative to the sample size.

You haven't provided much detail, but possible solutions may be reducing the number of parameters in your model, and/or the use of a shrinkage method (which I know very little about). The bootstrap may be useful to validate your model (`validate` in the `rms` package in R).

These things are covered in the book "Regression Modeling Strategies" by Frank Harrell.

Comment: I have around 25 variables in my model which has 4.75 lakh rows.

Comment: Is that 25 parameters in the model, or do some variables have more than 1 parameter? I had to google to find out that "lakh" is 100000, but that doesn't sound like too many variables. However, what proportion had the event?

Comment: well, most of the variable had categories. The total DF in my model is 48. So basically you can imagine that most of the variable had 2-3 categories and some 4-5. The event ratio was 3.79% in the dataset which was used to built the model and around  3.1% which I was scoring.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide information about the nature of data (cross-section, time-series, panel...)? In any case, it seems to me that one pssible problem is that there is a time trend that you are not take into acount. Another possibility is just that the data is not stationary, i.e, th past does not resemble the future at all and as time goes by your accuracy will decrease.

Finally, you have to think in relative terms. With no model, it seems that you'd predict only 3.79% of defaulters. Assuming you predict on a random bases, your accuracy would be very low (probaly near zero). On the other hand, with your model you'd predict with accuracy of 30%, which is much better. For instance, with 1000 people, without model you would say I expect only 30 of them to default, but they are equally likely to default. With your model, you will say: person 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 will default (and only one third of them will actually default). This is much better!

However, take a look not only at the true-positive rates, but also on false-positive reates of your model and false-negatives. A ROC curve may be a good way to look at this and calibate your model better to increase whatever the client wants (true-positive rates, true-negatives).